# Creating multiple divs according to variable

Tags: php, html, css, for-loop, foreach

Removed (by original poster) due to unclear formulation of question.
More accurate question: [Create divs associated to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318290/create-divs-associated-to-objects)

Comment: have you considered using javascript?

Comment: So basically you're asking how to use loops in your code?

Comment: @Ja͢ck I think it's a fair question if you're unfamiliar with loops. Plus, they provided their code and worded the question clearly.

Comment: To clear things up: yes I am very new to this programming thing, so I apolagise for not being able to simply look up a solution. But thanks for answering, I'll try them out tommorow as I will be at school to try them out

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $amountOfPersons; $i++)
{
    ?>
    <div class="fixed-size-square">
        <span><?php echo $someContentThatBelongsToPerson[$i]; ?></span>
    </div> 
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you'll get your database results returned to you in an array, the common way of doing this would be this in PHP:

```
foreach( $persons as $person ){
    echo '<div class="fixed-size-square">
              <span>I\'m a 200 x 200 px square with centered content no matter how many lines it takes</span>
          </div>';
    }
```

You could do it with the $amountPersons variable too (although I don't know why you'd want that if you get a result set back from the database), like this:

```
   for ( $i = 0, $i < $amountPersons, $i++ ){
       echo '<div class="fixed-size-square">
                 <span>I\'m a 200 x 200 px square with centered content no matter how many lines it takes</span>
             </div>';
   }
```

---

edit:

By the way, re-reading your question I realized you want to eventually put names in your divs, presumably the names stored in your database. You can do that with the first example, like this (this assumes the column name is your database is `personName` and that your result set is an array of objects.):

```
 foreach( $persons as $person ){
    echo '<div class="fixed-size-square">
              <span>Name: '.$person->name.'</span>
          </div>';
    }
```

Comment: Hi vanamerongen, For some reason the last one I tried echoes this (no errors just this): foreach( $persons as $person ){ echo '
$person-name 
' }

Comment: Do you have a pastebin link to the entire code? Well specifically the loop that you're using.

Comment: Since I work on this at school I don't have acces to the code right now and I will update you as soon as possible. Thanks anyway for the help so far.

Comment: Your code doesn't make a whole heap of sense... You're trying to iterate through an array of objects called "persons" that doesn't exist. I think it's safe to say you should get the basics of arrays and loops down first. Also you've got getter and setter methods, you use the setter to set the names, but you don't get them anywhere. That's only a few of the problems I see.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not tagged this as JavaScript, I can only assume you want a PHP approach to this, when you build the page I can only assume that you are running a query to get the records from the DB (since no code is provided).

All you need to do is wrap your div inside a for loop like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<?php

    for($i = 0; $i < $AmountPersons; $i++){
      echo '
      <div class="fixed-size-square">
        <span>I\'m a 200 x 200 px square with centered content no matter how many lines it takes</span>
      </div>
      ';
    }
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $amountOfPersons; $i++) {    ?>
    <div class="fixed-size-square">
        <span><?php echo $someContentThatBelongsToPerson[$i]; ?></span>
    </div> 
    <?php  } ?>
```