# Create divs associated to objects

Tags: php, html, class, object

I asked a similar question earlier but I haven't been able to find anything to help me. I have now updated my code to something working but I am now completely stuck.

This is my php code:

```
class person {
    public $name;
    public $SE;
    private $SD;

    function __construct ( $n, $s1, $s2 ) {
        $this->name = $n;
        $this->SE = $s1;
        $this->SD = $s2;
    }
}

$Obj = new person ( "ExampleName", 5, 5 );
```

I need to have seperate divs created for each person, containing their names in these divs. My main problem is that after these divs are created I need to have them sorted in a particular way (that isn't any importance to you) that requires for each div to have a ID associated to the original person from which the div was created.

I am otherwise able to create divs from a list of names but not from objects.
So:

1. I need a way to use foreach loops to create divs according to each object (person).
2. I need these divs associated with (linked to) that person.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what you mean by divs associated with that person but for first problem this should work.

Lets say you have an array of objects named $objs

```
foreach($objs as $obj)
{
   echo "<div>".$obj->name."</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but this should work:

```
// create an array of persons, I'm assuming that SE or SD is
// unique for each object
$persons = (
   new person("Allan", 1, 1);
   new person("Bobbo", 2, 2);
   new person("Cicci", 3, 3)
);
```

The objects could be sorted by name using `usort()`:

```
usort($persons, function($a, $b) {
   return $a->name > $b->name;
});


// loop through each object and output a div
// notice that the id will be unique and based on
// the `SE` member of the object, you can then reference
// a specific div from javascript $('#person-1') etc
foreach ($persons as $person) {
   print '<div class="person" id="person-' . $person->SE . '">' . $person->name . '</div>';
}
```

Using `jQuery` you could then get an object based on the unique id:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.person').click(function() {
    $.ajax('object.php', {
      type: 'post',
      data: 'id=' + $(this).attr('id').substr(7),
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(obj) {
         alert('You clicked on ' + obj.name + ' ' + obj.SE + ' ' + obj.SD);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

You would search in you `$persons` array to find the object with a corresponding `SE` (or whatever you deside to use as the unique identifer) value:

```
// object.php
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
   $id = intval($_POST['id']);
   foreach ($persons as $person) {
     if ($person->SE == $id) {
       // return json object
       print json_encode($person);
       break;
     }
   }
}
```